# What do city-state personalities mean?

Tags: civilization-5

There are 4 different personalities that I've seen for city-states: friendly, neutral, hostile, and irrational. I have never seen any use for them, though, except that influence over hostile city-states decreases at 1.5 times the rate of the others. What do the other personalities mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It affects the kinds of requests the city-state makes. From the game's documentation:

> A befriended **Friendly** City-State will usually make requests that require some peaceful action, like building a Wonder or constructing a Road to them.
>
> **Neutral** City-States are fairly even-keel, and try to mind their own business.
>
> Influence with a **Hostile** City-State drops more quickly than normal. They will also make requests to capture neighboring City-States more often.
>
> Compared with other City-States, an **Irrational** City-State is more random with the requests it makes.

Comment: Do you have a link to this documentation?

Comment: @phoenixheart6 This is the information that pops up should you put your mouse over the personality section on the city-state screen.